# Optimize PHP script using PostgreSQL count query

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm having some performance issues (speed of execution) with a very simple task, explained below. My code is to dumb to show here, so i'll explain the problem in detail:

Consider the following sql table, which stores daily rainfall data over ~12 years:

#### historic data

```
year, month, day, rainfall_observed
2001, 1, 1, 4
2001, 1, 2, 0
...
2012, 12, 31, 10
```

Now, consider another table with identical structure, but holding ~1 year of daily forecast data:

#### forecast

```
year, month, day, rainfall_forec
2013, 1, 1, 0
2013, 1, 2, 3
...
2013, 12, 31, 15
```

The problem: for each day of forecast data, count the **same (month, day)** in historic data, such that rainfall_observed > rainfall_forec.

#### Example

Consider the forecast entry

```
year = 2013, month = 3, day = 15, rainfall_forec = 10
```

Then i need to count in *historic data* every entry with *month = 3* AND *day = 15* WHERE *rainfall observed > 10* (easy with SQL). So, my output is a list with a count for each forecast day.

There's a lot way of doing this:

1 - Use a SQL query using inside a for loop (1 query per forecast day = 365 queries in a loop - i didn't test it yet)

2 - Query all the observed data and use nested loops for comparison (~ 365 * 12 * 365 comparisons...)

3 - Do some mix of the above or some math with Dates (but here missing data is a issue)

I'm currently using option 2, but i need it to be faster. I'll try option 1, but maybe i'm missing a simpler solution.

So, i appreciate any advice on how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the output you require? Just a list of 365 counts?

Comment: yes, the output is an array of counts, with 365 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a query like this:

```
SELECT r_for.year, r_for.month, r_for.day, count(r_for.rainfall_forec) 
FROM forecast AS r_for 
RIGHT JOIN historic_data AS r_obs 
ON r_for.month = r_obs.month 
  AND r_for.day = r_obs.day 
  AND r_obs.rainfall_observed > r_for.rainfall_forec 
GROUP BY r_for.year, r_for.month, r_for.day
```

Comment: There is [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/contrib-dblink-function.html) which may help you. But it's not usually installed by default so you need access to the database server.